# remote: missing/incomplete bugzilla conf (no bugzilla_url) error with gitzilla

Tags: python, bugzilla, pybugz

I have gitzilla config file setup at /ect/gitzillarc on remote central repository server with permissions all read and write.
    Content of the file code config is as follows

```
[/home/gituser/repositories/git-main/git-main.git/.git]
bugzilla_url: https://repo.example.com/bugzilla/
bugzilla_user: sboppana@example.com
bugzilla_password: s123
user_config: deny
allowed_bug_states: NEW, ASSIGNED, REOPENED
logfile: /var/log/gitzilla.log
loglevel: info`

python at 2.6.5
pybugz at 0.9.3 (tried with 0.8.0 also)
Gitzilla at gera-gitzilla-gitzilla-2.0-19-geceeaca.tar.gz
```

I get the error "remote: missing/incomplete bugzilla conf (no bugzilla_url)" with git push
Of course bugzilla_url value has the real name in my config file not the example name.

Tried many but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **xmlrpc.cgi** along with the bugzilla URL should solve this issue. This is the workaround for the problem in Pybugz.

For instance, if your bugzilla URL is `https://repo.example.com/bugzilla/` try using `https://repo.example.com/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi` This should work.